# How to fix this regular expression with JAVA?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String line ="Java8:9;C++:10;sql:7;C:8;C#:3";
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile("([\\w]+)[:]([0-9]+)|([\\w]+[^a-zA-Z: ]+)[:]([0-9]+)");
    Matcher m=p.matcher(line);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Skill: "+m.group(1)+" , Level: " + m.group(2));
    }

}
```

The output is

```
Skill: Java8 , Level: 9
Skill: null , Level: null
Skill: sql , Level: 7
Skill: C , Level: 8
Skill: null , Level: null
```

As you can see,the outputs with C++ and C# are not correct.
How to correct my regular expression?I tried so many ways but not good.:(

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions? Just split on `;`, then split on `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close: all you need to add is `#` and `+` to the list of characters recognized as part of language name, i.e. this part of the expression `([\\w]+)[:]` should be `([\\w+#]+)[:]`

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("([\\w+#]+)[:]([0-9]+)|([\\w]+[^a-zA-Z: ]+)[:]([0-9]+)");
//                              ^^
```

This fixes the problem ([demo](http://ideone.com/ThZH8u)).